# How to send PUT, DELETE HTTP request in HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, put, http-delete

I want to know if it is possible to send PUT, DELETE request (practically) through `java.net.HttpURLConnection` to HTTP-based URL.

I have read so many articles describing that how to send GET, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS requests but I still haven't found any sample code which successfully performs PUT and DELETE requests.

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried to use?

Answer (score 188):

To perform an HTTP PUT:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
    httpCon.getOutputStream());
out.write("Resource content");
out.close();
httpCon.getInputStream();
```

To perform an HTTP DELETE:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestProperty(
    "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
httpCon.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
httpCon.connect();
```

Comment: So is it possible that using java code you can delete mail from your mail account(using DELETE method) or Using post method you can create document(say like blogs.) ?

Comment: or Is it possible to send image/video/audio to server using POST method?

Comment: Yes. All these things are possible but really depend on the API supported by your mail/blog provider.

Comment: hello, I'm having troubles with the `delete`. When I run this code as it is here, nothing really happens, the request is not sent. Same situation is when I am doing `post` requests, but there I can use for example `httpCon.getContent()` which triggers the request. But the `httpCon.connect()` doesn't trigger anything in my machine :-)

Comment: In the examples above, I believe that you'll need to call httpCon.getInputStream() at the end to cause the request to actually be sent.

Comment: @Eric: Exactly, this is the case.

Comment: @Matthew, please add httpCon.getInputStream() to the examples

Comment: please open up this article, hope this might help you all...
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e43

Comment: I got " java.net.ProtocolException: DELETE does not support writing "

Comment: for delete should we specify which data to be deleted ? like "username":"abc" ?

Comment: @edisusanto the named resource (indicated by the URL) is the data which will be deleted.

Comment: @Matthew i've got the same error as Kimo_do which is `java.net.ProtocalException: DELETE does not support writing' ..

Comment: @edisusanto which line of code is throwing the `ProtocolException`?

Comment: Just a quick improvement on the delete code, it should look like this in order to work properly:
`URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setRequestProperty(
    "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
httpCon.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
httpCon.connect();
httpCon.getInputStream();`

Comment: `httpCon.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" )` is not necessary, only for errornous server implementations.

Comment: `httpCon.setDoOutput(true);` does not work on `delete()` operation.

Comment: Okay if I want to test the application by passing URL in the browser as `http://localhost:8080/spring-jpa/products?id=1` , how to differentiate them whether they are `GET`, `PUT`, or  `DELETE`

Comment: @MatthewMurdoch can you help me to solve this question, I got it while trying out your code for my task [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670608/how-to-call-the-github-api-form-httpsurlconnection-in-java?noredirect=1#comment70539532_41670608]

Comment: @MatthewMurdoch can this method be used to pass parameters for the APIs like github API

Comment: For PUT request, the InputStream returned by getInputStream is never closed. Is it OK?

Answer (score 28):

This is how it worked for me:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 13):

```
public  HttpURLConnection getHttpConnection(String url, String type){
        URL uri = null;
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try{
            uri = new URL(url);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod(type); //type: POST, PUT, DELETE, GET
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setConnectTimeout(60000); //60 secs
            con.setReadTimeout(60000); //60 secs
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "Your Encoding");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "Your Encoding");
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.info( "connection i/o failed" );
        }
        return con;
}
```

Then in your code :

```
public void yourmethod(String url, String type, String reqbody){
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        con = conUtil.getHttpConnection( url , type);
    //you can add any request body here if you want to post
         if( reqbody != null){  
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream out = new  DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                out.writeBytes(reqbody);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        con.connect();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String temp = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while((temp = in.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(temp).append(" ");
        }
        result = sb.toString();
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
//result is the response you get from the remote side
}
```

Comment: Getting 'java.io.IOException: unsupported method: put'  inJ2me sdk logger

Answer (score 12):

I agree with @adietisheim and the rest of people that suggest HttpClient.

I spent time trying to make a simple call to rest service with HttpURLConnection and it hadn't convinced me and after that I tried with HttpClient and it was really more easy, understandable and nice.

An example of code to make a put http call is as follows:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(URI);

StringEntity input = new StringEntity(XML);
input.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);

putRequest.setEntity(input);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(putRequest);
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for this. Spent many hours trying to get my code using `HttpURLConnection` to work, but kept running into an odd error, specifically: `cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode`. Following your advice worked for me. I realize this does not exactly answer the question, which asks to use `HttpURLConnection`, but your answer helped me.

Comment: @Deprecated use HttpClientBuilder instead

Answer (score 4):

UrlConnection is an awkward API to work with. HttpClient is by far the better API and it'll spare you from loosing time searching how to achieve certain things like this stackoverflow question illustrates perfectly. I write this after having used the jdk HttpUrlConnection in several REST clients.
Furthermore when it comes to scalability features (like threadpools, connection pools etc.) HttpClient is superior

Answer (score 4):

For doing a PUT in HTML correctly, you will have to surround it with try/catch:

```
try {
    url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
        httpCon.getOutputStream());
    out.write("Resource content");
    out.close();
    httpCon.getInputStream();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even Rest Template can be an option :

```
String payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?<RequestDAO>....";
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    headers.add("Accept", "*/*");
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(payload, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =
            rest.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, String.class);

     responseEntity.getBody().toString();
```

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've seen on SO.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple way for delete and put request, you can simply do it by adding a "`_method`" parameter to your post request and write "`PUT`" or "`DELETE`" for its value!