# how to create a file and write on it on URL

Tags: java, file, file-io, file-permissions

HI can anybody tell me how to create a file and write on it on the URl.

Actually I am using an applet and from theat I want to create a file on 
getCodebase(); so can any body tell me how can I do it

I have tried

```
URL url = new URL(/*url by codebase and the directory with file name*/);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
```

but it not worked

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

> Actually I am using an applet and from theat I want to create a file on getCodebase();

Well that wouldn't be very secure if you could do that, would it?

I think the route you want to take is to configure your HTTP server to handle PUT requests, and then form a PUT in Java.  That is described here:

- [How to send PUT, DELETE HTTP request in HttpURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051004/how-to-send-put-delete-http-request-in-httpurlconnection-looks-like-not-workin)

However, your applet probably needs elevated permissions (in other words, a signed applet that operates outside of the normal sandbox).  I'm not sure about that though; some connections are allowed back to the host so you might be OK.