# POSTing JSON and retrieving a response in Android

Tags: android, json, android-networking

I am trying to post a JSON message to a site and to retrieve a JSON message back.
java.net.ProtocolException: method does not support a request body: POST
Does anyone know what is wrong?  Thanks in advance

```
                 HttpURLConnection conn=null;
        try{
            URL url=new URL(urlString);
            String userPassword = userName +":" + passWord;
            byte[] bytes=Base64.encode(userPassword.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
            String stringEncoding = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
             conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
             conn.setDoOutput(true);
             conn.setDoInput(true);
             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + stringEncoding);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
            Log.i("Net", "length="+conn.getContentLength());
            Log.i("Net", "contentType="+conn.getContentType());
            Log.i("Net", "content="+conn.getContent());
            conn.connect();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Url Formation Connection", e.toString());
        }
```

//output{
            try{

```
            String requestString="{“ ";


            wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(requestString.toString());
            wr.flush();

    //input{
        BufferedReader rd = null;
        String response=" ";


            is = conn.getInputStream();
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer responseBuff = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                // Process line...
                responseBuff.append(line);
            }
            response = responseBuff.toString();
            Log.d("response", response);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("buffer error", e.toString());
        }finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    wr.close();
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this line: conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8"); try ("Content-Type", "application/json")

Comment: I took your suggestion but it didn't change the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the server you're connecting to doesn't allow POST operations. I would try a GET request first, to see if you have permissions for that web service method.

Also, you could try your luck with a simpler HttpClient, although I haven't tested this solution myself: http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-simple-httpclient-to.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I will try HttpClient.

Comment: I have been trying with HttpClient and I am getting the same result.

Comment: Its probably a server side problem like you said.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but can you try setting:

```
 conn.setDoOutput(false);
```

The documentation says: "Optionally upload a request body. Instances must be configured with setDoOutput(true) if they include a request body." [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Since you do not have anything in your body, might as well set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation Android has for [setRequestMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29) is minimal, however your error states that *POST* is not a valid method. Try using *PUT* instead:

```
conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
```

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051004/how-to-send-put-delete-http-request-in-httpurlconnection-looks-like-not-workin) for any tweaks you may need to make.