# Standard JAVA API that supports to send entity for HTTP Delete

Tags: java

Is there any JAVA client API that can support sending entity (message body) for HTTP Delete request

Comment: Check the following question, it's similar to yours.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051004/how-to-send-put-delete-http-request-in-httpurlconnection

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Apache HTTP Client: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html. It should provide the functionality you are looking for.