# how to make a httpDelete with Apache http client? in java

Tags: java, apache, http, rest

Hi i'm new in Apache http client, can you help me?

I have next parameter

{“name”:"goku"}

I sending this parameter to be removed.

please help me

Comment: Look into documentation before posting to stackoverflow

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/delete.html

for all mothods:
http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318557/apache-httpclient-deletemethod-example-needed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051004/how-to-send-put-delete-http-request-in-httpurlconnection

Answer (score 2):

Apache Http Fundamentals can be found here
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html

Specifically DELETE request is similar to GET and described here
http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/delete.html