# How to send body along with request while Consuming Restful web services in java?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, https

I need to consume Restful webservices. there i have to send some xml data as body in the request to Https service.

```
URL updateurl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/product");
HttpsURLConnection conn2 = (HttpsURLConnection) updateurl.openConnection();
conn2.setRequestMethod("PUT");
conn2.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
```

So here i have set some xml content in the body. Is there any method in HttpsURLConnection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send PUT, DELETE HTTP request in HttpURLConnection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051004/how-to-send-put-delete-http-request-in-httpurlconnection)

Comment: @VinayVeluri, It is working fine