# Java: Send GET PUT POST to an external API and get response

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am relatively new to JAVA and am trying to build a back-end application which will call another server where the data is present.

I have to do GET, POST, PUT and PATCH(can live without PATCH) operations to an external server in the intranet. I can hit the exposed service using postman app (using custom header)but want to do the similar action from my Java code, get the output in my Tomcat Server.

I have limitations in modifying dependencies to the POM file or adding jars to the library, so am looking for a solution other than Jersey.

Comment: Most of the place I look for provides me the answer for GET. I see some POST too, but my requirement is mainly for PUT.

Comment: you need to use `setRequestMethod("PUT")` as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (which extends [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)) to handle the http requests and these classes are part of JDK itself so you don't need any external jar files, I suggest you look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) for basics on these and look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) for examples.

> Most of the places, I look for provides me the answer for GET. I see
>   some POST too, but my requirement is mainly for PUT.

In order to place `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc.. http operations, you can use `httpConnectionObj.setRequestMethod("PUT")` or `httpConnectionObj.setRequestMethod("DELETE")` as given in an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051004/how-to-send-put-delete-http-request-in-httpurlconnection).

Comment: Sounds good, do you have a working example to show? I'm using Spring.

Comment: You can refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 1):

you could set up a simple java.net.Socket instance and implement the calls yourself - then you don't need any dependencies.

http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week12/22.html

Answer (score 1):

`java.net.HttpURLConnection` seems to be the way to go then. This might i.e. be initialized like so: `(HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection()`