# How to associate entity class with JSON request body in PUT?

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services

I am developing a web Service Rest in java, netbeans.

I've done some GET methods that are working, as follows:

```
        @GET
        @Produces("application/json")
        @Path("usuario")
        public String getUsuarios(@QueryParam("key") String key) {

            Conta c = ContaDAO.busca(key);

            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            JsonObject status = new JsonObject();
            if (c != null) {
                JsonArray array = (JsonArray) gson.toJsonTree(ejbUsuario.findAll());
                obj.add("dados", array);

                status.addProperty("codigo", 200);
                status.addProperty("mensagem", "OK");
                status.addProperty("descricao", "Sucesso na requisição");
                obj.add("status", status);

            } else {

                status.addProperty("codigo", 401);
                status.addProperty("mensagem", "Authorization Required");
                status.addProperty("descricao", erro401);
                obj.add("status", status);

            }
            return obj.toString();

        }
```

Now I need to do a PUT method, but it's not working.

```
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("bateria")
    public String postBateria(@QueryParam("key") String key, @QueryParam("mac") String mac, Tablet tablet) {

        Conta c = ContaDAO.busca(key);

        //ejbTablet.getBateria();

        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        JsonObject status = new JsonObject();
        if (c != null) {
            TabletDAO.postBateria(mac, tablet.getBateria());
        }
        else
        {
            status.addProperty("codigo", 401);
            status.addProperty("mensagem", "Authorization Required");
            status.addProperty("descricao", erro401);
            obj.add("status", status);
        }

        return obj.toString();

    }
```

For tests I'm using "Postman", follows the request I used:
[image]
[image]

If I make the request with empty body, the function is called and the tablet variable is obviously null.

If I do with the body filled as the image the function is not called. "HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request"

My Tablet class looks like this:

```
public class Tablet {
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String modelo;
    private Double tela;
    private String mac;
    private Double bateria;

    public Tablet() {
    }

    public Tablet(int id, String nome, String modelo, Double tela, String mac, Double bateria) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.tela = tela;
        this.mac = mac;
        this.bateria = bateria;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public Double getTela() {
        return tela;
    }

    public void setTela(Double tela) {
        this.tela = tela;
    }

    public String getMac() {
        return mac;
    }

    public void setMac(String mac) {
        this.mac = mac;
    }

    public Double getBateria() {
        return bateria;
    }

    public void setBateria(Double bateria) {
        this.bateria = bateria;
    }
}
```

The glassfish log: "Record: line 3: 1 mismatched input '"name"' expecting '}'"

I have seen other examples of PUT methods in java, but none deal with anything like what is happening.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140528/d%C3%BAvida-com-webservice-m%C3%A9todo-put-e-delete-como-implementar-em-java

[How to send PUT, DELETE HTTP request in HttpURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051004/how-to-send-put-delete-http-request-in-httpurlconnection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at the image in your put request. It's telling you "Unsupported Media Type" because your payload isn't json.

Instead, change the payload so that it looks like

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "nome": 14,
  "modelo": "TT Tanca",
  ...
}
```

This error (415) occurs when the server refuses the request since the resource is in a format that is not supported. Your controller consumes json so if you send it something that isn't json, the request will be refused.

This is why with an empty body it "works" but with your body (payload) it doesn't.